# How would I convert a const Class* to a Class*?

Tags: c++, linked-list, constants

I'm trying to insert something into a linked list, but the compiler tells me that I can't convert from a `const Student*` to a `Student*`. 
Each node contains a `Student *stud` and a `Node *next`. This is what I have written so far of the function:

```
void LinkedList::putAtTail(const Student &student){
    Node *p = new Node();
    p->stud = &student; //this is where I have trouble
    p->next - NULL;

    //then insert `p` into the Linked List
}
```

The compiler doesn't want to compile this, giving me `error: invalid conversion from ‘const Student*’ to ‘Student*’`.

How would I go about solving this, without changing the parameter of my `putAtTail(const Student &student)` function?

Comment: Please show the declaration of Node.

Comment: Because `&student` is completely different from `student` in this context.

Comment: You'd probably want to add a copy of the argument.

Comment: Taking the address of heap memory is almost universally a recipe for disaster. However, if you must, const_cast is what you need. I'm actually more curious what the line after the problem line is supposed to be doing.

Comment: By *not* doing it. The object might be marked as constant for a reason, and the reason might be to stop anyone from modifying the object. If you cast away the `const` and then modify the object, who knows what might happen (modifying constant data leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))? And if this is you own code for e.g. a school project, why make the argument `const` to begin with?

Comment: @WilliamKappler Even worse would be taking the address of something on the *stack*. Things on the stack tends to go out of scope a lot more than things on the heap.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oops, that's what I meant to say. This memory doesn't look dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I convert a const Class* to a Class*?

**Option 1:**

Make a copy.

```
p->stud = new Student(student);
```

**Option 2:**

Use `const_cast`.

```
p->stud = const_cast<Student*>(&student);
```

Use this option only if you carefully manage memory.

Comment: The copy is almost certainly what's intended. The student object even may be in read-only memory so that write-accessing it later (because the const information has been discarded) immediately crashes the program.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, I agree with you.